# SSRS 2008 Export to Excel Page Number problem

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have some reports that need to be exported to Excel by the users.  I'm displaying the page number in the page footer in a text box with this expression:  ="Page: " & Globals!PageNumber

When I test this in Visual Studio, the excel sheet I export looks fine.  Each page number is correct.  When I deploy the report and export it via the Report Manager each page number is "Page: 1".

How do I correct this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must configure the device information settings to use simple headers:

Find the rsreportserver.config file. Mine is located at C:\Program    Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS11.MSSQLSERVER\Reporting    Services\ReportServer\

Then edit the excel rendering section to use simple headers.

```
<Extension Name="EXCEL" Type="Microsoft.ReportingServices.Rendering.ExcelRenderer.ExcelRenderer,Microsoft.ReportingServices.ExcelRendering" Visible="False">
  <Configuration> 
    <DeviceInfo>
        <SimplePageHeaders>True</SimplePageHeaders> 
    </DeviceInfo> 
  </Configuration> 
</Extension>
```

Comment: unfortunately, this didn't change anything in my reports, still showing Page 1 of 1 on every page after exporting to excel

Answer (score 0):

See the last 2 paragraphs on [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159677.aspx). To sum up. You have to set the excel device information in the reportserver config file.